# How to perform daily maintenance on database records in MVC2 project?

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-2

A web application works with the database. Once a day, the database should be scanned and alerts should be sent to users.

From what I've seen out there, additional project has to be created which will be installed on the server and will work with the same database. Executable created by this project has to be installed in Windows scheduler to be activated once a day.

This seems complicated and inefficient: starting additional executable and working on the same database.

Is this the best possible way to do this?

Comment: why not do it in the database itself? what are you "scanning" for?

Comment: The scan has some logic, DB updates and email sending. This logic is not part of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have different possibilities: Windows Scheduler with an executable is a good one. Another possibility is to write a Windows Service which will execute the task in the background. [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is a good framework for this but the Windows Scheduler might be sufficient for your scenario. One thing is for sure: it is be better to perform these tasks outside of your ASP.NET application.